# What is the best strategy to save/load data (using python) that will be updated on a weekly basis over long periods of time?

Tags: python, database, dataframe, storage

I am working on a project that tracks my Spotify play history which I’ll use to generate personalized playlists.

I am saving my play history to a local dataframe (that I append to every week) as a pickle file. I also have a second dataframe that contains specific track features, also pickled locally.

I’m wondering 1) if there is a better way of structuring my data and 2) if I should be using other ways of saving my data.

Comment: is there a problem with the way your doing it? if not why optimize away a non existant problem?

Comment: I mean, almost certainly, this sounds like a better use-case for a database, but I think this question is too broad/opinion-based.

Comment: You can use [Python Anywhere.com](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/) which takes care of automatically running code in the cloud for free.